# Получение данных из формы jstl

Tags: http, jsp, jstl

Не могу разобрать в том как получить значение id из моей jstl формы , через цикл ForEach я вывожу названия которые мне нужны, но как получить их id для добавления в метод никак не пойму, буду очень благодарен за помощь в данном вопросе. Думаю для сторожил форума это очень простой вопрос.

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%--<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt" %>--%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>

<div class="link_container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/home">Home</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
<div class="terms_list_container">
    <table cellspacing="0" style="margin-top: 20px">


        <tr>

            <td style="font-size: large;">Select semester</td>

            <td style="padding-left: 50px">


                <select>

                    <c:forEach items="${semestr}" var="semestr">

                        <c:url var="chooseButton" value="/chooseSemester">
                            <c:param name="semId" value="${semestr.id}"/>
                        </c:url>

                            <option>${semestr.name}</option>



                    </c:forEach>

                </select>


            </td>


            <td style="padding-left: 20px"><input type="submit"
                                                  value="Select" id="button" onclick="window.location.href = '${chooseButton}'"></td>
        </tr>



        <tr height="80px" style="font-size: large; font-weight: bold;">

            <td colspan="3" >Semester duration:24 week</td>

        </tr>

        <tr style="font-size: large;">
            <td colspan="3">List of disciplines of the semester</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table style="margin-top: 20px">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 0" width="450px"><table cellspacing="0"
                                                        cellpadding="3" id="small_font_100_380" border="1px">
                <tr bgcolor="#DCDCDC" align="left" style="border-color: #8B8989;">
                    <th>Name of the discipline</th>
                </tr>

                <c:forEach var="discip" items="${allDisc}" >
                <tr>

                    <td>${discip}</td>

                </tr>
                </c:forEach>


            </table></td>

            <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0">

                        <table cellspacing="0">
                <tr>

                    <td style="padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 0"><input type="submit" value="Create semester"

                                                                            onclick="window.location.href = 'creteNewSemester'"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-bottom: 20px"><input type="button" value="Modify current semester"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-bottom: 20px"><input type="button" value="Delete current semester"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
    </table>
</div>
```

Прилагаю код моей jsp страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить данную сложность , не хватало тега   решение выглядит так :

```html
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/allSemestrsSem" method="get">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-size: large;">Select semester</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 50px">

      <select name="selectSemestr">

        <c:forEach items="${semestr}" var="semestr">
          <option value="${semestr.id}">${semestr.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left: 20px">
      <security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="select" /></td>
    </security:authorize>
  </tr>
</form>
```